# How to display NotFound when invalid hash is matched in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I did the steps to catch and handle invalid hashes with SAPUI5 but my application is not working.

[image]

When i try to navigate to NotFound view changing the Hash i only gets an Info message:

[image: But]

But the view isn't displayed.

[EDIT]:

Adding source code files:

Here i added the bypassed section

[image]

I've created the target in Targets section of the manifest:

[image]

This is the NotFound.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
   "my/path/controller/BaseController"
], function (BaseController) {
"use strict";

return BaseController.extend("my.path.controller.NotFound", {

    onInit: function () {
        var oRouter, oTarget;

        oRouter = this.getRouter();
        oTarget = oRouter.getTarget("NotFound");
        oTarget.attachDisplay(function (oEvent) {
            this._oData = oEvent.getParameter("data");  // store the data
        }, this);
    },

    // override the parent's onNavBack (inherited from BaseController)
    onNavBack : function (oEvent){
        // in some cases we could display a certain target when the back button is pressed
        if (this._oData && this._oData.fromTarget) {
            this.getRouter().getTargets().display(this._oData.fromTarget);
            delete this._oData.fromTarget;
            return;
        }

        // call the parent's onNavBack
        BaseController.prototype.onNavBack.apply(this, arguments);
    }

});
```

});

Here the NotFound.view.xml:

```
<mvc:View
   controllerName="my.path.controller.NotFound"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
   <MessagePage
      title="{i18n>NotFound}"
      text="{i18n>NotFound.text}"
      description="{i18n>NotFound.description}"
      showNavButton="true"
      navButtonPress="onNavBack"/>
</mvc:View>
```

And here the onInit method at the App controller:

```
onInit: function(){
        jQuery.sap.log.setLevel(jQuery.sap.log.Level.INFO);

        var oRouter = this.getRouter();

        oRouter.attachBypassed(function (oEvent) {
            var sHash = oEvent.getParameter("hash");
            // do something here, i.e. send logging data to the backend for analysis
            // telling what resource the user tried to access...
            jQuery.sap.log.info("Sorry, but the hash '" + sHash + "' is invalid.", "The resource was not found.");
        });

        oRouter.attachRouteMatched(function (oEvent){
            var sRouteName = oEvent.getParameter("name");
            // do something, i.e. send usage statistics to backend
            // in order to improve our app and the user experience (Build-Measure-Learn cycle)
            jQuery.sap.log.info("User accessed route " + sRouteName + ", timestamp = " + new Date().getTime());
        });
    }
```

and 
Any can help me?
Regards,

Comment: If you did the steps please provided your source code =) specially the routing section of manifest.json and piece of code which performs the navigation

Comment: Try this, in the "NotFound" target, add `"transition":"show"`. Comparing an [example from the demokit](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/e047e0596e8a4a1db50f4a53c11f4276.html), I see that is missing in your code.

Comment: Did you add `NotFound` route to `manifest.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/pxOkRSM8c97hXO6gkbpV

The key config is this on manifest.json:

```
 "targets": {
                "tgHome": {
                    "viewPath": "sapui5Example",
                    "viewName": "home"
                },
                "notFound": {
                    "viewPath": "sapui5Example",
                    "viewName": "NotFound",
                    "transition": "show"
                }
            }
```

To fire the 'not found' route, download the plunker and in the URL, after the hash just type anything and you will the the not Found Page (if you do it directly on plunker it won't work). Here is a pic:

[image: Not Found example]